# Solving $\int \sqrt {f(x)} \ dx=\sqrt{\int f(x)\ dx}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

> $$\int \sqrt {f(x)} \ dx=\sqrt{\int f(x)\  dx}$$

**My approach:**

I started by differentiating both sides and got:

$$\sqrt {f(x)}=f(x) \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\int f(x)\  dx}}$$

We can isolate the $2\sqrt{\int f(x)\  dx}$ in the left side:

$$2\sqrt{\int f(x)\  dx} = \sqrt{f(x)}$$

We can now square both sides:

$$4\int f(x)\  dx = f(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

We can again differentiate both sides and get:

$$4f = f'$$

And the solution of this equation is: $f(x)= Ce^{4x}$

**My question is the following:**

In the step where I putted a (1), it should be

$$4 \left|\int f(x)\  dx\right| = |f(x)|$$

Instead of $4\int f(x)\  dx = f(x)$, because $\sqrt{a}^2 = |a|$. How could I solve this differential equation if I did not make the assumption that $f(x) > 0$ and $\int f(x) dx > 0$ and got rid of the modulus?

Comment: You're thinking of the identity $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, which is not the same as $\sqrt a^2=|a|$. For $\sqrt a$ to be defined at all, $a$ must already be nonnegative; therefore $\sqrt a^2$ unambiguously evaluates to $a$.

Comment: Since in the question itself, $\sqrt {f(x)} $ is given, it follows from here that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all real $x$ whence it follows that $\int f(x) dx $ is $\ge 0$.so you don't really have to make an assumption  there. However, in the solution, you should put $C\ge 0$

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt{\int f(x)dx}$ is a differentiable function? How do you know that $f$ is a differentiable function?

Comment: Integration constants are missing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: since both sides were differentiated, why does it matter?

Comment: But perhaps the negative root will give some answers involving trigonometry like when trying to solve $y'' = -y$ @Koro

Comment: @Eduude: But if $f(x)$ is negative, $\sqrt{f(x)}$ will not be defined.

Comment: Are complex numbers allowed then? In such case, one has to be careful as to what it means by $\sqrt{\cdot}$, since there is no canonical choice of a square root on the complex plane.

Comment: Also note that, if there is no regularity assumption on $f$, then $$ f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{4x}, & x < 0; \\ 0, & x \geq 0; \end{cases} $$ is a solution of the equation with appropriate choice of antiderivatives.